# A misunderstanding about the Moret Bailly theorem

Tags: arithmetic-geometry

Sorry for the non-specific title, but this would be hard to fit in one line.

In "Groups as Galois Groups", theorem 10.27 says that there's some absolutely irreducible component of $\mathcal{H}_r^{in}(G)$ (if you don't know what this is, don't worry about it), call it $\mathcal{H}$, defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, such that it has an $\mathbb{R}$-rational point, and for every $p$ it has a $\mathbb{Q}_p$-rational point.
It goes on to say that *if* we had a local-global principle here, then we would get a $\mathbb{Q}$-rational point.

It seems that Moret Bailly would do:
http://people.math.jussieu.fr/~harris/SatoTate/notes/MoretBailly.pdf
if you pick $S_1=\{ \infty \}$ and $S_2=$ all the finite places.

What am I missing?

Comment: The two sets $S_i$ should be finite if I remember correctly. Have you looked at the original paper where Moret-Bailly proved his result? 

Comment: No, but that would make sense.

Comment: If this is the usual Moret-Bailly result that these modularity lifting theorem guys apply, then all it says is that there is a K-point for some number field K in which all primes in a given finite set split. It certainly can't control the degree of K.

Comment: Well, if S_2 is the set of all finite places, and you have a number field unramified over all of S_2, then that number field must equal Q. My guess is Brian's right.

Comment: Yes *definitely* the $S_i$ must be finite! The theorem is completely false otherwise---just take a standard counterexample to the Hasse principle like $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$.